# Ruby / Installation Package - What is the fastest way to setup a Ruby environment in Windows?

Tags: ruby

I currently work in a LAMP environment and use XAMPP to setup my dev environment in Windows. Are there similar installers that package all of the essential and commonly-used Ruby development tools?

Comment: Are you working with Rails, Sinatra, or Plain Old Ruby Objects?

Comment: @andrew I'm leaning towards rails but I haven't researched alternatives yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BitNami's [RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) might be what you are looking for. It includes, in one simple installer, Ruby, Rails, Apache and MySQL. Available for Windows and other platforms.